# YTPlayerView re-opening when dismissed

Tags: ios, uiview, youtube, embed

I have an embedded YTPlayerView:

```
YTPlayerView *player = [[YTPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:newCell.coverImageButton.frame];
[player loadWithVideoId:[self extractYoutubeIdFromLink:posting.postDictionary[@"uri"]]];
player.delegate = self;
[newCell addSubview:player];
```

It works fine, I click on the view and it presents a full screen player. but when I press 'done', the view is dismissed and then re-presented after a second or so.

Comment: I ended up using a library to extract the MP4 url and playing that (HCYoutubeParser)

Comment: mmm "Warning: This is not approved by the ToC of YouTube. Use at own risk." it is not so good, maybe i've found a solution but i need to test, just comment this line of code "window.setInterval(forcePlay, 5000);" in YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html

Comment: nice one! post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment this line of code `window.setInterval(forcePlay, 5000)` in YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the `YTPlayerView` class isn't required to get the result I wanted. this works perfectly enough:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@",tubeId]];
UIWebView *w = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
[self.view addSubview:w];
[w loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```